# select2 not displaying options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` library to send an ajax request:

I am getting the data back when I search for something but for some reason the results do not show up in the drop down.

```
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    ajax: {
    url:"/search/search",
    type:"POST",
    data: function (params) {
        // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
        var query = {
            search: params.term,
            type: 'public'
          }
        return query;
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        // Transforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(data)
        return {
            results: data.studentNumber
          };
      }
      // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
    }
  });
```

This is the data I can see in my console:

```
[
 {
   studentNumber :"12324"
 },
 {
   studentNumber :"12324"
 },

]
```

This is what the documentataion does:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/example/api',
    processResults: function (data) {
      // Transforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If this is the console log output, then you are receiving an `array` but trying to parse `data` as an `object`. Try returning `data` itself.

Comment: He's right, instead `return { data.studentNumber }` try plain `return data`. @KunalKukreja maybe create this as an answer for this question so you can gain points for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` you have received after transformation is an `array`. Calling `data. studentNumber` would yield undefined since data is not an object.

Just return the data itself since the `results` is anyway expected to be an `array`.

In simple words, change this:

```
return {
    results: data. studentNumber
};
```

to

```
return {
    results: data
};
```